# R data frame - finding length of streak

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R data frame which is just 1 row and looks like so:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
 1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0
```

I want to know how many 1s there are in a row starting from the first position. So this would be 4.

More examples:

(Example 1)

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
 0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0
```

would be 0 because the first position isn't even a 1.

(Example 2)

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
 1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0
```

would be 1.

How can I implement this?

```
numInStreakAtBeginning = function(row) {

}
```

Additionally, how can I implement a method that looks for the largest streak regardless of where it starts? For example,

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
 1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0
```

would be 3.

Comment: Probably you want `?rle`.

Comment: Right but how do I specify where the rle has to start and what value it has to take. Or furthermore, that it can start anywhere but has to have a certain value.

Comment: You can infer all of that from the output of `rle`, which will count all runs of all values.

Comment: First question: `r <- rle(row) ; ifelse(r$values[1] == 1, r$lengths[1], 0)`. Second question: `r <- rle(row) ; max(r$lengths[r$values == 1])`.

Comment: To be fair, the question was specific to 1's, and contingent upon the first value. I agree that knowing about `rle()` is the key hurdle to clear for this question, but there's somewhat more to the question. Furthermore, the question asks for a function that performs 2 tasks. This might seem like a simple question, but I see it as a spin-off of the "original" question, not a duplicate.

Comment: for the first question: what about `min(which(x==0)-1)` where `x` is your data frame (if you have more rows you can use `min(which(x[1,]==0)-1)` ?

Comment: @joran According to this post, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled, wouldn't you say the current question is more "similar" or "related"? I'm pointing this out b/c my reading of the question, even knowing rle, was that it was worth answering.

Comment: @rbatt The commands to get from the `rle` output to the final solution are short (each is a one-liner) and simple (`ifelse` and indexing one vector based on the values of another). Given the simplicity of answering the questions with the `rle` output, this seems like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function that returns a list of length 2, first element of the list is the length of the starting streak of 1's, the second element is the length of the longest streak of 1's.

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(20, 1, 0.5), nrow=1))

numInStreakAtBeginning <- function(row){
    runs <- rle(row[1,]) # convert to vector
    retList <- list() # store output

    if(!runs$values[1]){ # if the first value is 0, the length of the first streak is 0
        retList$firstStreak <- 0
    }else{
        retList$firstStreak <- runs$lengths[1] # if the first value is not 0, return length of first streak
    }

    retList$longestStreak <- max(runs$lengths[runs$values==1L]) # the longest streak of 1's, regardless of starting point

    return(retList)
}

numInStreakAtBeginning(test)
```